# Setting a default close action in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How can I set the red 'X' button to close the application? I know how to do it within a JFrame, but I don't know how to set it in a JOptionPane.

At the moment, clicking the red 'X' initializes the game instead of exiting the application.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Let's Play!", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

Comment: (1-) Same answer as you got in your cross posting: https://coderanch.com/t/688279/java/Setting-default-close-action-JOptionPane. If you don't understand a suggestion then ask a follow-up question, don't keep asking the question in different forums. Its frustrating when we spend time to help, but you ignore the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ConfirmDialog`. Depending on the action, you get different values (-1, 0, 1).

```
int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Test", "test", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
System.out.println(i);
```

The "X" returns `-1`, "Yes" returns `0` and "No" returns `1`. Now you can choose whether the game should start depending on the value

Answer (score 0):

Write your own `JOptionDialog` and observe the closing event:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyOwnCloseOption extends JOptionPane{

    //just to keep the names compliant
    public static String panel = "Your Message!";

    private Runnable closingRoutine;

    public MyOwnCloseOption(Runnable closingRoutine){
        super(panel, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        this.closingRoutine = closingRoutine;

    }

    public void showMessage(){
        JDialog dialog = createDialog("Let's Play!");
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                closingRoutine.run();
            }
        });
        //From Documentation (Java SE7): java.awt.Dialog:
        //"setVisible(true): If the dialog is not already visible, this call will not return until the dialog is hidden by calling setVisible(false) or dispose"
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //The Original code
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        MyOwnCloseOption myOwnCloseOption = new MyOwnCloseOption(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("Okay. -______-");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        myOwnCloseOption.showMessage();
        System.out.println("Starting the Game!");
        //something keeps the application still alive?
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```